# How do I get my cmake project to recompile when certain system headers (under /usr/include) are updated?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, include, include-path

I work on a project which makes use of several of my open source projects (for example [snaplogger](https://github.com/m2osw/snaplogger)) for which I create Ubuntu [packages on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Esnapcpp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages).

When I make an update to snaplogger, including changes to the header files, the project I work on doesn't recompile anything after the update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

less /usr/include/snaplogger/appenders.h     <-- I can see the change here (for example)
```

Now I know that cmake implicitly removes dependencies that reference header files found under `/usr/include`. What I'm wondering is: would there be a way for me to tell cmake to still add those dependencies for specific folders such as `/usr/include/snaplogger`?

I also know I can recompile everything and I just have to run a script to do so. It's just difficult to keep track and know whether I have to do that or not (and it takes a little time to recompile the entire project).

Comment: "(and it takes a little time to recompile the entire project)" as a workaround for this, you could use `ccache`: `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache` when configuring CMake. That will at least make it so that any files which didn't have a modified dependency could use the cached compile result rather than having to be recompiled.

Comment: @Justin, would that cache be capable of checking headers under `/usr/include` as well?

Comment: Yes, ccache should be able to check changes to /usr/include, but you may need to fiddle around with its configuration options.